# can't find mistake in sed substitution

Tags: bash, sed, find-and-replace

I'm trying to substitute include guards in headers with same include guards, prepended with `#pragma once`:

```
#ifndef _HELLO_H
#define _HELLO_H
```

Becomes:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _HELLO_H
#define _HELLO_H
```

Also, i want to leave line endings as-is. If it was LF then use LF, if it was CRLF then use CRLF.

I came up with following command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.h" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -E -e 's/#ifndef ([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(\r?\n)#define \1/#pragma once\2#ifndef \1\2#define \1/g'
```

But i got just line endings replaced in all headers, and no `#pragma once` added.

Command executed within MSYS2 terminal under windows.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause of a problem - it's because sed does't match multiple lines by default.

Also, found some solutions here: [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string)

Working solution for my special case (using perl instead of sed):

```
perl -0777 -piE 's/#ifndef ([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]+)(\r?\n)#define \1/#pragma once\2#ifndef \1\2#define \1/gs' `find . -type f -name "*.h"`
```